# how to be able to relate 2 dim tables in cube

Tags: ssas, dimensional-modeling

I think I have a designs issue (dimensional modelling). What I have:

Dimensions: Person, Brand, Market, Order Date Time Base (Role Playing), PersonDecile (Outrigger)

Facts: Sales

All the Dims relate to the fact table. I have a calculation on PersonDecile which is a distinct count of all customers.

What I need to know\want:

I want to be able to get that count of person from PersonDecile and be able to split it using the brand and market desc. Currently it isnt doing that when I bring the brand desc in the browser, it instead replicates that count for both brands.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code for your calculated measure as well.  Currently, I don't understand why this calculation is on PersonDecile rather than on Person.

Comment: Ah i understand, but for business needs i had to do it on that. I have literally just resolved the issue in ssas, with the use of dimensions usage.